# Getting [object Promise] in InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to print current in the innerHTML, but when trying to do so i am getting [object Promise] printed insted of current day, however in console log i am getting current day printed

```js
const url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata";

async function getData() {

  const response = await fetch(url)
  const data = await response.json()
  const timeZone = data.day_of_week
  const daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  const todayDay = daysOfWeek[timeZone]
  console.log(todayDay);

}

let currentDate = getData()

document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = currentDate;

console.log(currentDate)
```

```html
<div id="day"></div>
```

I am very new to JS, so I know i am missing something here

Comment: `currentDate` is a Promise, because that's what `getData` returns, since it's declared `async` - also, `getData` doesn't even return anything, so even if you handled the Promise correctly, you'd end up with `undefined` - try `let currentDate = await getData()` and you'll see

Comment: I had added `return todayDay` at the end of `getData function`, and even after `let currentDate = await getData()` i am getting error as `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: then use promises `.then`